# Can I add an IF statement into Private Sub in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Its just a database I'm trying to make it easier to populate data. The auto populating is already set up, when you enter a game PN(Data) it automatically adds the version(Data) and the name(Data). but I would also like to add the key(Data) but only if the key cell is blank.

Do the 3 auto populates if the key cell is blank otherwise only do the 2 auto populates. My code is below but it doesn't work. I've tried swapping "null" for "empty." I've tried "False" instead of "True" and swapped the subs around, I guess I tried it in reverse. Thanks for the help.

```
Private Sub Game_PN_AfterUpdate()

If Me.Key_PN = IsNull(True) Then

Me.Key_PN = Me.Game_PN.Column(3)
Me.Game_Rev = Me.Game_PN.Column(2)
Me.Game_Name = Me.Game_PN.Column(1)

Else:

Me.Game_Rev = Me.Game_PN.Column(2)
Me.Game_Name = Me.Game_PN.Column(1)

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `If Me.Key_PN="" Then...` ?

Comment: Your code is all sorts of weird. I recommend you follow a good tutorial. `IsNull(True)` returns `True`, because `True` is not null. Then you're comparing `True` to `Me.Key_PN`. Also, the colon after `Else` should not be present.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like:

```
Private Sub Game_PN_AfterUpdate()
    If IsNull(Me.Key_PN) Then Me.Key_PN = Me.Game_PN.Column(3)
    Me.Game_Rev = Me.Game_PN.Column(2)
    Me.Game_Name = Me.Game_PN.Column(1)
End Sub
```

That is, if your `Key_PN` field is null, then populate the `Key_PN` field with the value held by `Game_PN.Column(3)`; update the other two fields regardless.